Power Supply for Magnetic Vice (using a microwave transformer)
I am building a “Magnetic Vise” using a set of microwave transformers.
I was unsure of the power-supply needs to power such a device.
I am re-posting this question with more details as requested.
Thank you, to those who had earlier offered suggestions to try help resolve my power supply issues.
To find my power-supply needs,  I tested the microwave transformer with a 12 V DC, 6 A automotive battery charger.
Using the automotive battery charger as a power supply, the microwave-transformer's seems to have reasonable amount of magnetic power.
So I purchased a  manufactured power supply, with similar specs for the magnetic-vice.
But this purchased power supply (120 V AC to 12 V DC 10 A) is not able to run the transformer.
If you watch the LED power indicator-light on the manufactured power supply, it cycles on and off every couple seconds.
What is wrong, have I purchased the wrong power supply?
As requested earlier, I  have posted below the different voltages while running the transformer with both the battery-charger and the purchased power-supply.
First, here is a link to the power supply that I am having trouble with.
Its an Amazon product.
https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01JL0UJEQ?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1
I hooked up the 12 V, 6 A DC automotive battery charger and tested the voltage with the transformer hooked up and then  with an open circuit.
With the battery charger not-connected, its output is 15 V DC.
When the battery charger was connected, the voltage at the transformer was  3 V DC.
The transformer had good magnetic power with the automotive charger.
Based on my finding with the battery charger, I purchased from Amazon an 120 V AC to 12 V DC (10 A) power supply.
As mentioned earlier, this power supply performed poorly.
When hooked up, I noted an odd behavior, as the power indicator light on the power supply was cycling on and off every 1 or 2 seconds.
Yet earlier I tested this power-supply on a DC fan, and it worked fine running a fan.
So here is the voltage readings for the Amazon power supply.
When the power-supply was open circuit, the output voltage was 14.32 V DC.
When the power supply was hooked up, the voltage reading at the transformer was 0.4 VDC.
So I thought this was odd that the Power supply was cycling and the voltage was cycling from “0” V to .4 V (about every 2 seconds).
Any idea's why this amazon purchased power-supply is cycling and unable to power my microwave transformer?
Maybe I need a higher voltage?
Possibly you have a suggestion for a different power supply with different specs for this home-made magnetic vice?
Thanks again for for your expertise and for taking the time.
Jim

Welcome! You will be flux density limited when using any core, so as soon as you have reached Bmax, increasing the current will just give you more losses, not more "magnetic power". Can you show with a drawing or image how you mechanically set this up? An unmodified core will short out just about all the magnetic flux to be within the core itself, whereas you need the opposite. Also, you only need enough voltage to overcome the IR losses in the wire (low), and you need preferably constant current regulation.

@Antonio51 Think of an electromagnet.

Your Amazon supply offers this caution: Safety features: Automatic overload cut-off, over Voltage cut-off, automatic thermal cut-off, short circuit protection. Which of these protection "features" might be active is unclear.

@winny ok. Noted.

@Jim please don't open up a new user and question the circumvent the system

Try putting all your microwave transformers in series. If the current is the supply's nominal current or slightly below, you're done. Otherwise remove one of the transformers after the other …

which ex-transformer winding are you using? what it its resistance?

I was able to find a smaller, but different  12 v DC power supply with no safety built in's.
This smaller (1.5 amp)power supply was able to run the microwave transformer successfully.
So, I need a new power supply.
Any suggestions for the ideal Dc voltage and Amperage for the new power supply?
The Ohms reading for each microwave-transformer.
2.3 ohms and  4 ohms.
The  Magnetic Vice (below) is from YouTube by Schematix
There is a  fly-back diode for safety.
The Schematix Magnetic Vice design, is offered at this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orsmjiCMot
